# what does __getattr__ do when it return a class of itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I read an example on a website.

**The code of the example is here:**

> ```
> class Chain(object):
>
>     def __init__(self, path=''):
>         self._path = path
>
>     def __getattr__(self, path):
>         return Chain('%s/%s' % (self._path, path))
>
>     def __str__(self):
>         return self._path
>
>     __repr__ = __str__
>
> print(Chain().status.user.timeline.list)
> ```

**The output of this code:**

> '/status/user/timeline/list'

I understand what "__getattr__" does when it returns a value, but it becomes more complicated when it returns a class itself.

**What I think the step of this code will do is like this:**

> 1. *print(Chain().status.user.timeline.list)* starts.
> 2. *Chain().__init__* will initialize *self._path* by *path* which is ''
> 3. *Chain().__getattr__* path parameter will become "status".
> 4. *"__getattr__"* will return *Chain('%s/%s' % (self._path, path))*
> 5. *%s/%s* becomes "/status"
> 6. Then the new Chain class which was created just now will soon initialize.
> 7. ***self._path* will assigned by *path* which is '' again.**
> 8. *Chain().__getattr__* parameter *path* will become "user".
> 9. "__getattr__" will return Chain('%s/%s' % (self._path, path))
> 10. *%s/%s* becomes "/user"
> 11. loop...

**My question:**

> Because of the initialization, every time the "__getattr__" create a
>   new Chain, the self._path will be assigned by '', so **I think the
>   final output should be "/list".** but the result is not like that.
>
> I don't understand what is happening inside this process.

Thank you everyone who read this question and try to give me an answer.

Comment: It returns a new `Chain` whose path is the current path plus the extra bit. Your step 7 is wrong. The path doesn't somehow go back to being empty.

Comment: @khelwood You are right. I forgot this point. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a Chain whose path is '/status'. Now you call `.user` on it.

In `__getattr__`, `self` is current Chain (so `self.path` is `'/status'`), and the `path` parameter is the name of the attribute you're trying to access, which is `'user'`. The `__getattr__` method builds a new string from `self.path` and `path`, giving `'/status/user'`. It passes this string to `Chain()` to give a new `Chain` object whose path is `'/status/user'`.

Etc.